# Trigger.io barcode.scan throwing Java error

Tags: android, trigger.io

Using Trigger.io's [barcode api](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/barcode.html) in an application that only contains boilerplate HTML and the following JavaScript:

```
forge.barcode.scan(function (value) {
    alert("You scanned: "+value);
});
```

I get the following error in the log:

> Forge Java error: RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Full error entry:

> [INFO] D/Forge   ( 1109): Returned: {"content":{"message":"Forge Java
>   error: RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has
>   not called
>   Looper.prepare()","type":"UNEXPECTED_FAILURE","subtype":null,"full_error":"java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Can't create handler inside thread that has not called
>   Looper.prepare()
>       at
>   android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:197)
>       at
>   android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:111)
>       at
>   android.app.Dialog.(Dialog.java:107)
>       at
>   android.app.AlertDialog.(AlertDialog.java:114)
>       at
>   android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:931)
>       at
>   android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:950)
>       at
>   io.trigger.forge.android.modules.barcode.API.scan(API.java:68)
>       at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>       at
>   io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeApp.callJavaFromJavaScript(ForgeApp.java:247)
>       at
>   io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeJSBridge$1.run(ForgeJSBridge.java:17)
>       at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>       at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>       at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)\n"},"callid":"35E46BC5-1C17-4354-B09B-BE67B5FCD513","status":"error"}

**Update:**

Below is my code:

File `config.json`

```
{
    "config_version": "2",
    "name": "Scan to Web",
    "author": "email@email.com",
    "version": "0.1",
    "platform_version": "v1.4",
    "description": "An empty app created by default",
    "modules": {
        "logging": {
            "level": "DEBUG"
        },
        "barcode": true,
        "contact": true,
        "file": true,
        "is": true,
        "media": true,
        "prefs": true,
        "request": {
            "permissions": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
        },
        "tools": true,
        "reload": true
    }
}
```

File `default.js`

```
forge.barcode.scan(function (value) {
    alert("You scanned: "+value);
});
```

File `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Hello world!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try one of two things:

1) Turn Reload module on in your app configuration. I know it sounds weird or stupid, but trust me, it should resolve your problem for now. I had very similar issue with Request module when Reload was off.

2) Change "platform_version" in your src/config.json from "v1.4" to "v1.4.25". I think last platform version is a bit broken.

Comment: It's already enabled. This is under the `modules` property in config.json `"reload": true`

Comment: I had this problem yesterday. It was one of those weird bugs... I turned Reload and it worked. Did you change anything in you app config? Or is it the same it would be in a newly created app?

Comment: I just added `"barcode": true` under modules. Just to be sure, the app config you're referring to is `src/config.json` right?

Comment: Right. You only have this piece of JS in your app? Could you post it in context of the rest of your code?

Comment: I'm sorry, the Reload module suggestion helped me fix my problem with different module, but doesn't seem to fix your problem with barcode. I think this is happening since Thursday evening. One more thing to try is to change "platform_version": "v1.4", to "platform_version": "v1.4.25".

Comment: Changing the platform version to `v1.4.25` seems to have fixed it. Thanks. Please update your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Changing platform version to v1.4.25 fixed it for me as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There was a threading problem in Trigger.io version v1.4.26 - it's fixed in [v1.4.27](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-27) upwards.

Sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 0):

This exception is usually raised if you are calling a UI-related code from a thread other than the UI-thread. If this is Java I would use:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // place your code here
    }
});
```